# How to use primeng autocomplete in angular formly(How to use completeMethod event in formly JSON)

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, primeng, angular-formly

//I am using primeng lib in my lib. As I am implementing autocomplete functionality in formly so created autocomplete type with the help of"https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-custom-template-3yvkcd" link.

**AutoCompletecComponent**

```
    import { Component} from '@angular/core';  
    import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';     
    @Component({
      selector: 'formly-autocomplete',
      template: `<p-autoComplete [suggestions]="results" 
      (completeMethod)="searchCity($event)"></p-autoComplete>`,
    })
    export class FormlyAutoCompleteComponent extends FieldType {       
    }
```

**ParentComponent - trying to us searchCity function here**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `<form [formGroup]="form">
    <formly-form [form]="form" [fields]="fields" [model]="testModal" [options]="options"> 
   </formly-form></form>`
export class ParentComponent{
constructor(){}
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
  "fieldGroup": [
    {
      "key": 'city',
      "type": 'autocomplete',
      "templateOptions": {
        "label": "City name",
        "placeholder": "Enter city"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": 'country',
      "type": 'select',
      "templateOptions": {
        "label": "country name",
        "placeholder": "select country"
      }
    }
  ]
] 
/*How to use it here, where this function triggers on completeMethod event from autoCompleteComponent?*/

searchCity(event){
//do something
}
}
```

Comment: could you share your code please.

Comment: Just need input on how to use that completeMethod event in json file. Stuck here only. If i can get this I'll work further. This is the starting point if you aware of formly

Answer (score 0):

`Formly` doesn't map methods from JSON, there are 2 ways to accomplish such functionality which you may check on 
https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/1819#issuecomment-571117573

Comment: Getting this error initially ' There is no type by the name of "autocomplete" '

Comment: there is no `autocomplete` type for `primeng`, you'll need to create a custom type first which you may check in our doc https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field

Comment: Thanks for the info. The given link in the answer is not exactly suitable for my question. Edited the question. Please check and reply.

Comment: check my reply in Github https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/2041